Co authoring in Excel and Word when using SharePoint 2016 and Microsoft 365 (Formerly Office 365) client
As per this article, Excel for Microsoft 365 does support co-authoring and every user must use same version.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-file-is-locked-for-editing-6fa93887-2c2c-45f0-abcc-31b04aed68b3
I just want to confirm if that is the case i.e. if I use Excel 365 desktop client, will it support co-authoring with SharePoint 2016 on-premise?

Did you check my answer?

Yes I did check your answer. Not entirely sure about Excel still because there is a lot of conflicting information from Microsoft.

No, Excel for Microsoft 365 will not support co-authoring files hosted in SharePoint Server 2016.

Note that SharePoint On-Premises sites (sites that are not hosted by Microsoft) do not support co-authoring. If you aren't sure which one you're using, ask the person in charge of your site, or your IT department.

Source: Collaborate on Excel workbooks at the same time with co-authoring
